# Select with "default" value and specific overwrite value

Tags: sql, select, sql-view

maybe a silly question ..

i would have to like one SQL table containing rows which should be used as default, and then rows for specific values ..

example table A:

```
ID; Filter; Class; Value
1 ; %     ; Car  ; 100 kg
2 ; %     ; Bus  ; 500 kg 
3 ; my    ; Car  ; 600 kg
```

table B:

```
Query; 
my;
yours;
```

i know i can have both values for car by creating a view and joining the Filter IN ..

```
SELECT 
A.Class, A.Filter, B.Query, A.Value
FROM B
  INNER JOIN A ON A.Filter in (B.Query, '%')
```

this would return

```
CAR, %, yours, 100 kg
CAR, my, my,  600 kg
BUS, %, yours, 500 Kg
```

My problem. if i get back 2 rows (default % and CAR) i **ONLY**
want to have the specific row with "my" and not the default with "%"

so this i expect as result :

```
CAR, my, my, 600 kg
BUS, %, yours, 500 KG
```

same if there would be more specific Overwrites for BUS, CAR, ..

Any suggestion how to solve this in SQL only ?

Comment: `ON A.Filter in (A.Class, '%')` are you sure?

Comment: sorry typo B.Query